# Accessing a field by variable in array of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I am running into an issue when attempting to access individual fields of objects stored within an array.

I have an array of non-uniform objects, we'll call *cache*.

```
var cache = new Array();
```

The *put* function allows adding items to the array.

```
function put(item, value) {
  cache[item] = value;
}
```

An example of usage:

```
var item_abc = { item_a: 'some value', item_b: 'another value' };

put('ITEM_ABC',item_abc);
```

The problematic function is called *update* which updates a *field* for an *item* in the array with a new *value*.

```
function update(item, field, value) {
  cache[item][field] = value;
}
```

Here is the troublesome code:

```
update('ITEM_ABC','item_a','a new value');
```

In the browser, this seems to work fine, but in a "--use_strict" Node.js environment, it runs into issues. I'm assuming this is related to precedence and the way in which multi-dimensional arrays are evaluated versus object fields.

How do I reference a object field without knowing the field name at runtime, when the object itself exists within an array?

Reading from the field in question always returns *undefined*.

```
function check(item, field) {
  console.log(cache[item][field]);
  if (typeof cache[item][field] !== 'undefined')
    console.log('field exists');
  else
    console.log('field undefined');
}
```

Running:

```
check('ITEM_ABC','item_a');
```

Outputs:

```
undefined
'field undefined'
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error you're running into when using `use strict`?

Comment: I don't see any JSON in this question. JSON is a data serialization format. It sounds like you're talking about JavaScript objects.

Comment: There is no _error_, but `typeof cache[item][field]` is always `undefined`

Comment: Start with `var cache = {};` (JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays.)

Comment: If u use strict mode u can't have a variable named package.

Comment: Working fine for me https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w5k29WXGQNIdxvJ6CL4-2FnETs78YVpG

Comment: I've made some edits to address these comments. The main issue seems to be with checking whether or not `typeof cache[item][field] !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend simplified `get` and `put` functions. If you would like to implement a specialized `update`, it should utilize `get` and `put`

```js
const cache =
  {}

const get = (key) =>
  cache[key]

const put = (key, value) =>
  cache[key] = value

const update = (key, field, value) =>
  put ( key
      , { ... get (key) || {}, [field]: value }
      )

put ('foo', { a: 1 })

console.log (get ('foo')) // { a: 1 }

update ('foo', 'a', 2)

console.log (get ('foo')) // { a: 2 }
```

Above, we write functions as simple as possible. But perhaps a more flexible way to write `update` would be something like `Object.assign` where you can update an object using another object

```js
const cache =
  {}

const get = (key) =>
  cache[key]

const put = (key, value) =>
  cache[key] = value

const update = (key, obj) =>
  put ( key
      , Object.assign (get (key) || {}, obj)
      )
      
put ('foo', { a: 1, b: 2 })

console.log (get ('foo')) // { a: 1, b: 2 }

update ('foo', { a: 2, c: 2 })

console.log (get ('foo')) // { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2 }
```

If you want to support multiple caches, you can wrap the `get`, `put`, `update` interface in another function. Below we demonstrate the ability to interact with two separate caches, `c1` and `c2`

```js
const makeCache = () =>
{ const cache =
    {}

  const get = (key) =>
    cache[key]

  const put = (key, value) =>
    cache[key] = value

  const update = (key, obj) =>
    put ( key
        , Object.assign (get (key) || {}, obj)
        )
        
  return { get, put, update }
}
 
const c1 = makeCache ()
const c2 = makeCache ()

c1.put ('foo', { a: 1 })
c2.put ('foo', { a: 2 })

console.log (c1.get ('foo')) // { a: 1 }
console.log (c2.get ('foo')) // { a: 2 }

c1.update ('foo', { z: 3 })

console.log (c1.get ('foo')) // { a: 1, z: 3 }
console.log (c2.get ('foo')) // { a: 2 }
```

Lastly, using an object `{}` for the `cache` is not really ideal as the `key` is always converted to a string before the value can be associated to it. The same problem happens when we use an array `[]` as you did in your original code. Watch what happens when we use a non-primitive value as a key...

```js
const cache =
  {}

const get = (key) =>
  cache[key]

const put = (key, value) =>
  cache[key] = value

const update = (key, obj) =>
  put ( key
      , Object.assign (get (key) || {}, obj)
      )

const k1 = { foo: "bar" }
const k2 = { hello: "world" }

put (k1, 1)

console.log (get (k1)) // 1
console.log (get (k2)) // 1 ???
```

Above, even though we never `put` a value for `k2`, we can still `get` a value because the string representation of `k1` and `k2` are the same – each is converted to `[object Object]` before the value is stored. Below, we avoid this problem using `Map`

```js
const cache =
  new Map

const get = (key) =>
  cache .get (key)

const put = (key, value) =>
  cache .set (key, value)

const update = (key, obj) =>
  put ( key
      , Object.assign (get (key) || {}, obj)
      )

const k1 = { foo: "bar" }
const k2 = { hello: "world" }

put (k1, 1)

console.log (get (k1)) // 1
console.log (get (k2)) // undefined

put (k2, 2)
   
console.log (get (k1)) // 1
console.log (get (k2)) // 2
```